# Access to Mongodb in Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, kubernetes

I created a Mongodb service according to the Kubernetes [tutorial](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/meanstack/).

Now my question is how do I gain access to the database itself, with a client like Robomongo or similar clients? Just for making backups or exploring what data have been entered.

The mongo-pod and service only have an internal endpoint, and a single mount.

Is there any way to safely access this instance with no public endpoint?

Internally URI is `mongo:27***`

Comment: I'd eagerly encourage to use the mongo shell (https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/client/) as mongo client and `mongodump` and `mongorestore` for backups. Use GUIs like Robomongo as a complement, not as a main client.

Comment: You can access to shell of running container through docker exec command if You know container name (something like k8s_mongo): `docker ps --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}" | grep "${name}" | cut -f1 | xargs -I NAME docker exec -i NAME  echo 1`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The kubernetes cmd-line tool provides this functionality as @ainlolcat stated

```
kubectl get pods
```

Retrieves the pod names currently running and with:

```
kubectl exec -i mongo-controller-* bash
```

you get a basic bash, which lets you execute

```
mongo
```

to get into the database to create dumps, and so on. The bash is very basic and has no features like completion and so on. I have not found a solution for better shell but it does the job

Answer (score 24):

You can use `kubectl port-forward mypod 27017:27017` and then just connect your mongodb client to `localhost:27017`.

If you want to stop, just hit `Ctrl+C` on the same cmd window to stop the process.

Comment: Perfect for accessing from an external client like Robomongo running in your computer

Comment: you can also connect to a pod using the service name using it as `kubectl port-forward svc/mongodb 27018:27017` instead of podname so you don't have to look up the ever changing pod name

Comment: Hello, how can I use this service on this port outside my cluster?

Answer (score 9):

when you create a service in kubernetes you give it a name, say for example "mymongo". After the service is created then

The DNS service of kubernetes (by default is on) will ensure that any pod can discover this servixe simply by its name. so you can set your uri like

```
uri: mongodb://**mymongo**:27017/mong
```

In addition the service IP and port will be set as environment variables at the running pod.

MYMONGO_SERVICE_HOST

MYMONGO_SERVICE_PORT

I have in fact wrote a blog that show a step by step example of an app with nodejs web server and mongo that can explain further

http://codefresh.io/blog/kubernetes-snowboarding-everything-intro-kubernetes/

feedback welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @grchallenge is correct but it is deprecated as of in 2021

All new comers please use

```
kubectl exec  mongo-pod-name -i -- bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one if you need to access direcly the database (just be careful):

```
kubectl exec -it mongo-pod-name -n <namespace> -- mongo
```